# Definition of diamond objects

Tags: c++, c++17

Assuming I have a diamond hierarchy as shown in the code below.

```
class A {

public:
    A() {}
    int a = 3;
    virtual void aa() {}
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    B() : A() {}

    int b() { return 4; };
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    C() : A() {}
};

class D : public B, public C {
protected:
    int d = 45;

public:
    D() : B(), C() {}
};
```

I have a main like this:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<D>();
}
```

The above main results in segmentation fault. However adding `a.release()` to main caters for the segmentation fault. Why is that?

Comment: A does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the diamond hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is not a virtual Dtor in A.  Without the Dtor you can see the segfault is happening in object destruction when running with GDB:

```
eddy@eddy-VirtualBox:~/deleteme$ g++ -std=c++14 -O0 -g test.cpp       
eddy@eddy-VirtualBox:~/deleteme$ gdb a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/eddy/deleteme/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff76f2c01 in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x555555769e88) at malloc.c:3123
3123    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff76f2c01 in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x555555769e88) at malloc.c:3123
#1  0x0000555555554f6d in std::default_delete<A>::operator() (this=0x7fffffffddd8, __ptr=0x555555769e88) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:78
#2  0x0000555555554e07 in std::unique_ptr<A, std::default_delete<A> >::~unique_ptr (this=0x7fffffffddd8, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:268
#3  0x0000555555554b68 in main () at test.cpp:33
```

Adding a virtual destructor to class A fixes this:

```
public:
    A() {}
    int a = 3;
    virtual void aa() {}
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
```